# In Android Activity's intent action?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

If an activity 'A' declares two actions in its manifest. and another activity named as 'B' starts the activity A by setting one of its action.

Is it possible for activity A to know which action is been set for calling ?

**Activity B:**

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,secondactovity.class);
    intent.setAction("lets.open.via.dashboard");
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity A Manifest file:**

```
  <activity android:name="com.example.testing.secondactovity">
       <intent-filter >
           <action android:name="lets.open.via.home"/>
           <action android:name="lets.open.via.you"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, in `Activity` A simply call:

```
getIntent().getAction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi ya figured it out ---

```
 if(getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("lets.open.via.home")){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"oops",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Thanks everyone